# Error in Fileutils.copydirectory using apache commons java

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am using apache.commoms.io 1.1 for copy directory but it is throwing error now. Am using java 1.7 and windows machine. i tried with 2.4 jar but the problem not fixed.

Error:

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time
  at java.io.File.setLastModified(File.java:1258)
  at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyFile(FileUtils.java:686)
  at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:653)
  at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:607)
```

Code:

```
 FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(imageconv1), new File(destpath+"/" + new File(imageconv1).getName()));
```

Comment: Check files in source directory (or subdirectory) some of them have time in deep future.

Comment: It has been working for the past 3 months but now suddenly it is throwing error

Comment: Try to debug it. Only way I know time can be negative is because of long overflow.